# How can i remove extra "s" from django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am really very much irritated by the extra "s" added after my class name in django admin eg class 'About' in my model.py becomes 'Abouts' in admin section. And i want it not to add extra 's'. Here is my model.py file-

```
class About(models.Model):
        about_desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

        def __unicode__(self):              # __str__ on Python 3
                return str(self.about_desc)
```

Please anybody suggest me how django can solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django fix Admin plural](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587707/django-fix-admin-plural)

Comment: Although your question is answered below, this information is readily available in the django tutorial.  Don't get irritated until you do a little study.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can add another class called `Meta` in your model to specify plural display name. For example, if the model's name is `Category`, the admin displays `Categorys`, but by adding the `Meta` class, we can change it to `Categories`.

I have changed your code to fix the issue:

```
class About(models.Model):

    about_desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __str__ on Python 3
        return str(self.about_desc)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "about"
```

For more `Meta` options, refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [Model Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) in the django documentation.

Within a Model you can add `class Meta` this allows additional options for your model which handles things like singular and plural naming.

This can be used in the following way (in english we do not have sheeps) so `verbose_name_plural` can be used to override djangos attempt at pluralising words:

```
class Sheep(model.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sheep'
```

Answer (score 3):

inside `model.py` or inside your `customized model file` add class meta within a Model Class.
If not mentioned then a extra 's' will be added at the end of Model Class Name which will be visible in Django Admin Page.

```
class TestRoles(model.Model): 
   class Meta: verbose_name_plural = 'TestRoles'
```