# How to remove the post-fix 's' from the database table name in Django Model, which is automatically added by Djanog

Tags: python, django

can anyone tell me, how can I get rid of the postfix 's' from the db_table name. Below is the sample model code. When is see this model through the admin portal I see the database table name is 'countrys'. How can I remove this 's' from my db_table name?

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    population = models.IntegerField()
    alpha2Code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    languages = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "country"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587707/django-fix-admin-plural

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django fix Admin plural](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587707/django-fix-admin-plural)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [verbose_name_plural](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural) on `Meta` to 'countries'.